# Add multiple object in angularjs scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on Galleries and Pictures. I'm using Flask, AngularJS, MongoDB (and mongoengine). I displayed all my object thru an API.

I got 2 kinds of objects:
- Galleries objects define by id:int, title:string, owner:string, date:string, content:array[], etc...
- Pictures objects define by id:int, title:string, owner:string, date:string, etc...

In the Content of Galleries which is an array, I got all the ids belonging of the gallery.
[MongoDB sample][1]

When the user click on the concerned gallery, I try to list all the pictures in a HTML page template.
For that I'm using a $scope variable in the controller and ng-repeat on the HTML side.

**Controller**:

```
    $scope.gallery = Galleries.get({id: $routeParams.id}, function (gallery) {
        for (var i = 0; i < gallery.content.length; i++){
            gallery.picture = Picture.get({id: $scope.gallery.content[i].split('-')[1]});
        }
    });
```

**HTML**:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="pict in gallery">
        <td>{{pict.fileID}}</td>
        <td>{{pict.legend}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Unfortunately, only the last one picture in the content is displayed. The global variable in the scope isn't feeding at each content index.

How can I do to put all the picture object in an only one scope variable for using ng-repeat in the HTML view?

Thanking in advance,
Have a nice day.

Comment: can you show your code of the functions `Galleries.get` and `Picture.get`?

Comment: Hi, it's perhaps little bit tricky, but Could I used an array?

Answer (score 0):

The get function is providing from the API (mongoengine):

```
@app.route('/api/galleries/<id>', methods=('GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'))
 def galleries(id):
     return handle_request(Galleries, id)


@app.route('/api/picture/<id>', methods=('GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'))
def picture(id):
    return handle_request(Picture, id)
```

Then the handle_request looks like:

```
def handle_request(model, id):
    def get_object():
        try:
            obj = model.objects(id=id).first()
        except:
            raise NotFound
        if not obj:
            raise NotFound
        return obj

    if request.method == 'GET':
        check_allowed('READ', model)
        try:
            return jsonify(get_object().to_dict())
        except NotFound:
            abort(404)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        check_allowed('UPDATE', model)
        try:
            obj = get_object()
        except NotFound:
            obj = model(id=id)
        obj.from_dict(request.json)
        obj.save()
        return jsonify(obj.to_dict())
```